# JSON Encode and Decode

Tags: php, json

I have an array like this:

```
Array (
    [utm_source] => website
    [utm_medium] => fbshare
    [utm_campaign] => camp1
    [test_cat] => red
    [test_sub] => Category
    [test_ref] => rjdepe
)
```

which I `json_encode` and put into a cookie. I take it from the cookie and now want to decode it but I get a blank screen. I am confused as to what is wrong. To me this JSON looks correct:

```
{"utm_source":"website","utm_medium":"fbshare","utm_campaign":"camp1","test_cat":"red","test_sub":"Category","test_ref":"dodere"}
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

My code:

```
$value = array(
    'utm_source' => 'website',
    'utm_medium' => 'fbshare',
    'utm_campaign' => 'camp1',
    'test_cat' => 'red',
    'test_sub' => 'Category',
    'test_ref' => 'rjdepe'
);
$value = json_encode($value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);
```

Other Page:

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
$cookie = json_decode($cookie);
print_r($cookie);
```

Comment: @dqlopez: it's a result of `print_r`

Comment: Can you add a snippet of how you're actually doing this? Also, do your web server logs show anything relevant? Make sure you have error_reporting set to something high enough to report it properly, and maybe make sure display_errors is set to true.

Comment: @dqlopez it's a result of `print_r` :o

Comment: I tried you JSON on a validator, and it is indeed valid JSON.

Comment: added my code, what do you mean its a result of print_r?

Comment: nevermind was telling some dude who commented on your `Array` being invalid when it's actually the result of `print_r`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try base64_encoding it like such:

```
$value = array(
    'utm_source' => 'website',
    'utm_medium' => 'fbshare',
    'utm_campaign' => 'camp1',
    'test_cat' => 'red',
    'test_sub' => 'Category',
    'test_ref' => 'rjdepe'
);
$value = base64_encode(json_encode($value));
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);
```

Other Page:

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
$cookie = json_decode(base64_decode($cookie));
print_r($cookie);
```

Answer (score 3):

Before your:

```
print_r($cookie);
```

Do:

```
json_last_error();
```

Does it return anything? If you are getting a blank screen, it may be because the parser is failing, likely the results of the `"`'s in the json string within the cookie being escaped `\"`.
Try:

```
$cookie = json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE['TestCookie']));
```

**Update**

So I used the following code, and received the following output:

```
    $value = array(
        'utm_source' => 'website',
        'utm_medium' => 'fbshare',
        'utm_campaign' => 'camp1',
        'test_cat' => 'red',
        'test_sub' => 'Category',
        'test_ref' => 'rjdepe'
    );

    var_dump($value);

    setcookie('TestCookie', json_encode($value), time()+86400);

    echo $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];

    print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE['TestCookie']));
```

**Output**

```
array(6) {
  ["utm_source"]=>
      string(7) "website"
  ["utm_medium"]=>
      string(7) "fbshare"
  ["utm_campaign"]=>
      string(5) "camp1"
  ["test_cat"]=>
      string(3) "red"
  ["test_sub"]=>
      string(8) "Category"
  ["test_ref"]=>
      string(6) "rjdepe"
}

{
    "utm_source":"website",
    "utm_medium":"fbshare",
    "utm_campaign":"camp1",
    "test_cat":"red",
    "test_sub":"Category",
    "test_ref":"rjdepe"
}

stdClass Object
(
    [utm_source] => website
    [utm_medium] => fbshare
    [utm_campaign] => camp1
    [test_cat] => red
    [test_sub] => Category
    [test_ref] => rjdepe
)
```

If you notice, encoded is an array. The json string is a string. The decoded string is an object.

You can type cast this to an array:

```
$value = (array) json_decode($_COOKIE['TestCookie']);
// Or
$value = json_decode($_COOKIE['TestCookie'], true);
```

Also,

Depending on your configuration, PHP may escape special characters in your cookie, which seems to be what your JSON decode error is relaying.

Try doing:

```
json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', $_COOKIE['TestCookie']), true);
```

Comment: I get 4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX when I do json_last_error(); I tried what you gave me but `strip_slashes` does not work did you mean `stripslashes`?

Comment: I tried to decode the data when it is not a cookie and it seems to decode fine but if I pull it from the cookie it does not work.