# post php array via ajax jquery to different php file

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, post

i have a doubt about sending php array to another php file using ajax-jquery, if we send the php array via jquery post using some input type hidden value , it's convert array as string. so the another php file not receiving as array value it's receiving as a string. i know php explode implode function for that. but in codeiginter the given array is differ see the following array i need to send

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [pro_id] => 1731 [pro_code] => 2564 [pro_name] => Lakudi [pro_des] =>  IS USED IN ALL FOOD SWEETNER INSTEAD OF SUGAR [pro_det_des] => ALSO AVAILABLE VARIES COLORS AND SHAPES CUBES BIG AND SMALL BALLS AND YELLOW, BROWN AND BLACK COLORS [pro_pack_des] => BULK AS WELL AS CONSUMER PACKING CAN BE OFFERED 30 KGS BULK ALSO AVAILABLE [pack_length] => 65 [pack_breadth] => 85 [pack_height] => 110 [cbm] => 0.608 [case_netweight] => 30 [case_grossweight] => 31 [price_INR] => 1100.00 [price_USD] => 0.00 [slab1] => [slab2] => [slab3] => [slab4] => [s1price] => [s2price] => [s3price] => [s4price] => [prolabel] => [exp_on] => 2013-12-31 [und_grp] => 16 [image_name] => 19442_94.jpg [image_name1] => 0 [image_name2] => 0 [image_name3] => 0 [crt_date] => 2013-06-11 [up_date] => 2013-06-11 [status] => active [admin_status] => deactive [list] => 0 [supplier_id] => 100 [bin] => 0 ) )
```

i was send this array using input type hidden sample code

```
<input type="hidden" class="datapro" value="<?php print_r($data)?>">
```

my jquery-ajax code

```
$('.clickfu').click(function(){
        var view = $(this).attr('id');      
        var datapro = $('.datapro').val();
        $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>productajax',{typ:'proview',view:view,datapro:datapro},function(data){                                               
             $(".prolist").replaceWith(data);
            // alert(data);
        });
        return false;
    })
```

in this array. how can i use explode implode function to convert the string as array. so please kindly give me guidance for solve this issue. thanks advance

Comment: Using `<?php print_r($data)?>` to set value of input is NOT a good idea, never, ever!

Comment: I think you might want to use json_encode, which takes a php object/array and turns it into a json object string. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to though.

Comment: i want to just post as a array and get as a array. how can i do this in jason_encode. give me some example

Comment: @tamil_arvu take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907466/json-encode-and-decode) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707618/json-encode-and-decode-on-php) and also the [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: thanks hashem quolami

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code structure :

in your script :

```
$('.clickfu').click(function(){

        var value1 = $('#$value1').val();

        var value2 = $('#$value2').val();

        var value3 = $('#$value3').val();

        var value4 = $('#$value4').val();

            $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>/controller_name/method_name',
                        data:{
                                value1 : value1,
                                value2 : value2,
                                value3 : value3,
                                value4 : value4,

                             },
                        success : function(res){
                            if( res == 1 )
                            {
                                alert(' Success..!!');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('Oops..!! Something went wrong.Please try again.');
                            }
                        }
                    });
        });
```

in your Controller :

```
    public function method_name()
    {
          if(isset($_POST))
            {

                $insert_array = array(

                                   'value1'       => $_POST['value1'],
                                   'value2'       => $_POST['value2'],
                                   'value3'       => $_POST['value3'],
                                   'value4'       => $_POST['value4'],

                                );
                $res = $this->model_name_db->insertValues($insert_array);
                if( $res > 0 )
                {
                   echo"1";exit;
                }  
                else
                {
                   echo"0";exit;
                }  
            }
            else
            {
                // your action
            }

    }
```